# php image checkbox deleter

Tags: php, image, checkbox

I am having trouble making a image deleter in php i do not know what is wrong

PHP:

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['dcheck'])) {
    $img_dir = "Uploads/";
    $image = $_POST['dcheck'];
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM Photos WHERE PhotoNumber = '".$image."'") or die(mysql_error());
    echo 'The image(s) have been successfully deleted.';
    } else{
        echo 'ERROR: unable to delete image file(s)!';
    }
    ?>
```

HTML:

```
<form  action="Admin3.php" method="post">
<?php 
while($check = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
echo '<img class="images2" src= "/PhotographyMML/Uploads/resized' . $check['PhotoName'] . $check['PhotoType'] . '" height="100" width ="100" ><input type="checkbox" name="dcheck[]" value="'. $check['PhotoNumber'] .'" />';
}
?>
<input type="submit" value="Delete Image(s)" />
</form>
```

Comment: You should try re-writing your first code, it appears to have no logic at its current state (with the if-else statement).

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your dcheck variable is an array.  You will want to create an outer loop around the existing query code you have and foreach through the array, deleting each time.

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['dcheck'])) {
    $img_dir = "Uploads/";
    foreach ($_POST['dcheck'] as $image) {

        mysql_query("DELETE FROM Photos WHERE PhotoNumber = '".$image."'") or   die(mysql_error());
        echo 'The image(s) have been successfully deleted.';
        } else{
            echo 'ERROR: unable to delete image file(s)!';
        }
    }
?>
```

A small optimization would be to alter the query so it uses WHERE  A small optimization would be to alter your delete query so that it uses WHERE PhotoNUmber IN (1, 2 ...).
This would cause your deletion to happen in one query rather than N queries.

What seems to be missing is any code to actually remove the original file you're alluding to.  That would require some sort of file deletion function typically utilizing http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php